# Problem with having different background color for QWidget for hover and selected state

Tags: qt, widget, qtstylesheets

Trying to style qt widget, I need different colors for hover, while the mouse is pressed, disabled and normal state. I m not able to change color for the pressed state. Please, help?

```
QWidget
{
background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);
}
QWidget:hover
{
background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);
}
QWidget:pressed
{
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: QWidget is not a QPushButton, if you need pressed state, you'll have to implement it all by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) does not have ":hover" and ":pressed" pseudo-states supported. However, you can simulate these pseudo-states through [dynamic properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#dynamic-properties). Still, in order to use such a mechanism, you would have to do the following things first (you can choose whichever you like):

1. Install event filter on your [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) instance. This event filter would have to react to the following events: QEvent::Enter and QEvent::Leave for hover state. And then, QEvent::MouseButtonPress would need to be used for the mouse press state. Regarding event types, you can read more [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum). Also, there might be circumstances where you would need to react to the current mouse position. However, by not knowing your exact use case it is hard to tell if you need that or not.
2. Implement custom class that would be a child of [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html). By doing so, you would need to override the following methods:

   [virtual void enterEvent(QEvent *event)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent)

   [virtual void leaveEvent(QEvent *event)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#leaveEvent)

   [virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent)

Now, in each implementation you would have to set your own dynamic property. The following example illustrates just how to set a dynamic property and ensure it gets styled on run-time:

```
ui->someWidget->setProperty("property_applied", true);

// This is the limitationn. You can read more about it here: https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets
ui->someWidget->style()->unpolish(ui->someWidget);
ui->someWidget->style()->polish(ui->someWidget);
```

When styling by dynamic properties, you can set the following stylesheet:

```
#someWidget[property_applied=true] {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

#someWidget[property_applied=false] {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

In other words, it would be not too hard to implement the following styling mechanism through usage of event filters or custom widget implementation and dynamic properties:

```
QWidget {
    background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);
}

QWidget[hover=true] {
    background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);
}

QWidget[pressed=true] {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```